# Identity-Aware Proxy Authorization Error 403 org_internal

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

I have a Python Streamlit app hosted in GCP via App Engine. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPMWWLf9W-Q), I added an Idenity-Aware Proxy to secure the app.

The IAP is activated and the OAuth consent screen it set to internal.
In the IAP settings, I added myself and a fellow both with the "IAP-secured Web App User"-role.

While I can access the app after login with my associated google account, he gets and "Error 403: org_internal" error when login within his associated google account.

What I already tried:

- Setting the OAuth consent screen to external (test mode) and added both of us
- Adding him to our GCP organization

None of both approached worked. He just can't access the app after all.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you asked your friend to try incognito? Not sure but it may be possible that they have two Google accounts logged on their browser.

Comment: We already tried to clear the cache by using `url/_gcp_iap/clear_login_cookie` and made sure to login using the correct account.

Comment: Try checking your organization policies. I don't have tools to see your project details, so if you have a Free Trial or Paid support plan, I suggest using it and reach out to a [support representative](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) who can review your configs.